# How to see the value of a variable being used in an sql statement during a server trace?

Tags: sql-server-2005, profiler

I have a stored procedure which has SQL statements that take variables. For example,

```
update customer set cust_id = @newcust_id where issuedate < @transferdate and cust_id = @oldcust_id
```

The values of the variables are assigned earlier in the SP.

How do I show the values of these variables during a server trace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can trace them explicitly into the Profiler using a custom event, via [`sp_trace_generateevent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177548.aspx):

```
declare @tracedata varbinary(8000);
set @tracedata = cast(@transferdate as varbinary(8000));
exec sp_trace_generateevent 82, 
        N'@transferdate', 
        @tracedata );
set @tracedata = cast(@oldcust_id as varbinary(8000));
exec sp_trace_generateevent 82, 
        N'@oldcust_id', 
        @tracedata);
```

You need to modify your Profiler session to monitor for the user [User-Configurable Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175164.aspx), otherwise you won't see the generated events. I would also comment out the call to `sp_trace_generateevent` in production once the debugging is done. The call is not critically expensive (specially if there is no monitoring listening for it), but it should be removed none-the-less.

*Updated*

The `exec` call doe snot allow for a CAST to be inlined in the parameter list. I modified the code to show how to cast it before the exec. The value will be in the `BinaryData` column, in HEX representation (so `'daf'` will show up as `0x646166`).

Comment: Here is the code I used to test this sp in SSMS:

declare @@oldcust_id  varchar(10)

set @@oldcust_id = 'daf'

exec sp_trace_generateevent 82, N'@oldcust_id', cast(@oldcust_id as varbinary(8000));

Comment: And for some reason, it gave me an error saying Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '@oldcust_id'. I really can't see any problem with the statement. Is the comma or I don't know..

Comment: Is it realy `@@oldcust_id` in the code, or is that double `@@` just a typo in your comment? Also, is better to post this as an edit to your original question, is difficult to read code in comment

Comment: It's a typo sorry. It has one @ in the code

Comment: I figured it. Looks like we don't need the last parameter. This is what I did: declare @@oldcust_id varchar(10) set @@oldcust_id = 'daf' exec sp_trace_generateevent 82, @@oldcust_id. Two changes here: 1) I removed the 3rd parameter. 2) I unquoted the second parameter. If your parameter is something other than a varchar, than cast it into a different variable and use the second variable instead of the original one.

Comment: I had to use two @ for each instance of it in the comment because the website doesn't allow me to use only one, as it considers it a reply to a user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tracing you will catch all params in your trace.

If you want to see the last input from a given connection use [DBCC INPUTBUFFER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187730.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Change the stored procedure to PRINT them before the UPDATE runs, or use the debugger built in to SSMS rather than Profiler.